# Simple KendoUI Grid Not Populating

Tags: php, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Several different questions on this topic, but none of the answers helped, so thought I'd try and see if anyone can figure this out..

So I have a simple grid, here is the HTML/PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo PROPERTY_TITLE; ?></title>

<!-- LOAD KENDO CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kendo.default.min.css"/>

<!-- -------------- -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"> // REQUIRED FOR THIS APPLICATION TO FUNCTION </script>

<!-- LOAD KENDO -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kendo.all.min.js"> // REQUIRED FOR THIS APPLICATION TO FUNCTION </script>
<!-- ---------- -->
</head>

<body class="bg">
<div class="grid-box7 box2close min_height_700" style="display: none;">

    <script>
        // Function to build the grid
        function generateRawDataGrid() {
            var from = $("#fromDate").val();
            var to = $("#toDate").val();

            <? if ( isset($_GET['source']) && is_numeric($_GET['source']) ) { ?>
            var source = <? echo trim($_GET['source']); ?>;
            <? } else { ?>
            var source = '';
            <? } ?>




            $(".li_current_report").html("Raw Statistical Data");
            $("#rawDataGrid").kendoGrid({
                columns: [
                    {   title: "Action",
                        field: "comment"
                    }
                ],
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "data/get_stats.php?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&source=" + source + "&rt=3"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "data"
                    },
                    type: "json"
                },
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSize: 15,
                    pageSizes: [
                        15,30,60,100
                    ]
                },
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                selectable: "row",
                reorderable: true
            }); // END: Report Grid

        } // END: Function generateGrid()

    </script>

    <div id="rawDataGrid" >
        <!-- Grid is here -->
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the datasource code:

```
// Build SQL statement
        $SQL_STATS = "
                    SELECT      comment
                    FROM        stats_tracking
                    WHERE       date_entered between '" . $FROM . "' AND '" . $TO . "'  AND
                                action_detail1 NOT In(" . $excludeIPs . ") AND active = 1";

        if ( is_numeric($_GET['source']) && trim($_GET['source']) != "" ){
            $SQL_STATS .= "
                            AND source = '" . $_GET['source'] . "'";
        }
        $SQL_STATS .= "
                    ORDER BY    date_entered DESC
                ";

        // Get the data
        $statResult = mysql_query($SQL_STATS); // Run the actual query.

        $dataOut = array(); // Create empty array for temp data to store in main output array

        while ( $stat = mysql_fetch_object($statResult) ) {
            $dataOut[] = $stat;
        }

        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo "{\"data\":" . json_encode($dataOut). "}";
```

The output seems fine - and LINTs fine as well, here's a piece of it:

```
{"data":[{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Doctor Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Doctor Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Doctor Site Visit"},{"comment":"View Contact Information"},{"comment":"Doctor Site Visit"}]}
```

But the grid isn't rendering.  I've used several JSON validators.  And the browser is seeing this output as APPLICATION/JSON.

Any ideas?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: I don't see where you are calling this method. generateRawDataGrid()

Comment: And you're right.. there wasn't in that code.  There was in the new page I created - and I copied and pasted the wrong one 8/.  That said, I found it.  The call to the method had only "generateRawData()".  Jeez.. it sometimes only takes another pair of eyes.  Thanks Rick!

Comment: @RickS Put your comment in an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are calling this method. `generateRawDataGrid()`

Perhaps you need to create a document.ready() function and call it from there.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   generateRawDataGrid();
});
```